# Why isn't \\ interpreted as a blackslash in this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning to use Java's Pattern and Matcher, and this is an example code snippet in my book. It works as the author describes, but what I don't get is why `\\.` ends up being a dot instead of a backslash (the \\ part) and a dot (the . part). Does the compiler not read from left to right?

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class SplitTest {
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
       String input= "www.cs.cornell.edu";                          

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
      String pieces[] = p.split(input);
      for (int i=0; i<pieces.length; i++){
            System.out.println(pieces[i]);    
            }



   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being interpreted once when parsing the string literal, and once by the regex compiler.

`"\\."` -> `"\."` - string literal
`"\."` -> literal `.` - regex compiler

Comment: This is the reason Java needs Regex support like other languages, where it would not use quotes but instead `/\./`.

Comment: Java need the @-string like .NET languages had. It won't break the annotation syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You must double-escape the string literal.
   `"\\\\."`
Because Java interprets the string literal `"\\."` as `\.`, which is not what you expect.
Try this: `System.out.println("\\.")`, and what you see is what you get in the regexp.

EDIT: Your input string is `"www.cs.cornell.edu"`. Do you know what you are doing? Maybe you are trying to split by the dot (`\.`), which its Java literal is `"\\."` as you typed.

Maybe you are trying to match a BACKSLASH then a DOT, which means its regex is `\\\.`, which its Java literal is `"\\\\\\."`

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I *was* trying to split by the dot. Or rather, the author was. And the code does it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified a bit, like so:

`public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "www.cs.cornell.edu";
        String[] pieces = input.split("\\.");
        for (String piece : pieces) {
            System.out.println(piece);
        }
    }
}`

The "double back slash period" works just as expected in this case, but the formatting on stackoverflow requires "quadruple back slash period" which is kind of odd.