# How to replace substring with quotes in Java?

Tags: java

I have a string:

```
str="{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998],
[60.680103564162927,56.834305549577387],[60.679971577383398,56.833005837614643],
[60.679813193248009,56.832846980836457],[60.678546120164683,56.832760331400671],
[60.678229351893869,56.831850500219574],[60.677622212708137,56.831893826015182],
[60.676830292031028,56.832139337910085],[60.67624955020122,56.832818097713471],
[60.676275947556981,56.833655699235088],[60.676328742268893,56.834724336044253],
[60.677411033860842,56.834695454369324],[60.677490225928629,56.834478841097273],
[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998]]]}"
```

Now i want to delete all `\`:

```
str.replaceAll("\\","");
```

And get error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
```

Okey i says. Another wish its delete first and last quotes:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("\""),str.lastIndexOf("\""));
```

And i get a string:

```
"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998],
[60.680103564162927,56.834305549577387],[60.679971577383398,56.833005837614643],
[60.679813193248009,56.832846980836457],[60.678546120164683,56.832760331400671],
[60.678229351893869,56.831850500219574],[60.677622212708137,56.831893826015182],
[60.676830292031028,56.832139337910085],[60.67624955020122,56.832818097713471],
[60.676275947556981,56.833655699235088],[60.676328742268893,56.834724336044253],
[60.677411033860842,56.834695454369324],[60.677490225928629,56.834478841097273],
[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998]]]"
```

Only last `}` was deleted.

What i doing wrong in this code snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace("\\", "");
```

Works fine for your case.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target,CharSequence replacement)
```

Replaces
 [each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

```
String s = "abc" + "\\" + "def";
System.out.println(s);
```

And it prints out the following -

```
abc\def
```

The \ is an escape character in both the String and in regex.

Comment: @KliverMax str.replaceAll(); takes regular expression. Try only str.replace("\\", "");

Comment: This function works fine for all CharSequences but i cant do anything only with `/`.

Comment: @KliverMax The \ is an escape character in both the String and in regex.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23146/discussion-between-achintya-jha-and-kliver-max)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `str.replaceAll("\\\\","");` ?
(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640386/500478)

Comment: I think that \\\\ -> \\ becouse its not help.

Comment: Could you provide a piece of source code? Using your example I can't know if your string really contains backslashes or if they are here to escape quotes in your Java String...

Answer (score 1):

Use either of one,

```
str.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

or

```
 str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

When you type `"\\"`, this is actually a single backslash (due to escaping special characters in Java Strings).

Regular expressions also use backslash as special character, and you need to escape it with another backslash or using a `DOT(.)` So in the end, you need to pass `"\\\\"` or  `"\\."` as pattern to match a single backslash.

Answer (score 1):

```
       System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
```

Output:

> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998],
>   [60.680103564162927,56.834305549577387],[60.679971577383398,56.833005837614643],[60.679813193248009,56.832846980836457],[60.678546120164683,56.832760331400671],
>   [60.678229351893869,56.831850500219574],[60.677622212708137,56.831893826015182],
>   [60.676830292031028,56.832139337910085],[60.67624955020122,56.832818097713471],
>   [60.676275947556981,56.833655699235088],[60.676328742268893,56.834724336044253],
>   [60.677411033860842,56.834695454369324],[60.677490225928629,56.834478841097273],[60.677938980978993,56.834449959232998]]]}

Comment: I think that \\\\ -> \\ becouse its not help